# Use sort order from server in CoreData and feed to NSFetchedResultsController without property to sort by

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsorderedset

I need to find a way to perserve the sort order given by the server, when using a fetchedresultscontroller, even though the parameter used to sort by in the server is not returned with the data.

Each set of objects can be sorted in various ways, that is returned as json in an array with the correct sort order

I have them in different ordered sets contained by entities that also contain meta data, and sort by a parameter that is the same in all items, but the order in my ordered set is not used to sort by anyway.

The target iOS version is 6.1-7.0

My fetch request predicate is:

`fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in %@.items", itemList];` where items is an `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *items;` so the predicate clearly refers to the ordered set.

Any better predicates and sort descriptors for working with ordered sets?

Any better ways to structure my model?

Thank you!

Comment: For the fetch request (or the FRC) it is actually *irrelevant* if you use ordered or unordered relationships. A sort descriptor does not (and cannot!) use the order imposed by an ordered relationship. Just imagine two ordered relationships A->C, B->C - which order should a fetch request on C use? So an additional attribute (as said below) is the only solution.

Comment: I thought that a predicate using the specific ordered set would work, that is how I reasoned. I added that to my question.

Comment: The predicate has no influence at all to the order of the returned objects. The predicate is only used as a filter to decide which objects to return.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. We try to go without core data in this project. But I still want to know more about how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to abandon using ordered sets. They are not very flexible and you will run into issues like the one you have all the time. (One problem is that they are neither derived from `NSArray` nor `NSSet` so some standard manipulations become very difficult.)

I suggest to introduce a `position` attribute to your entity or entities that need to be in a particular order. You can store this the moment the data comes in. The rest is trivial.

Comment: The problem is that I want to store multiple sort orders for a set if items. So I would need a list of `position` entities with information on what the name of the sorting is. Is it still the easiest way? Or the only way?

Comment: As you know you, always have an array of sort descriptors indicating what to sort first. The position attribute is only there to persist an order that is arbitrary (as opposed to the alphabetical sorting of a name) and that comes from the server or from the user interface (e.g. rearrangeable table view rows).

Comment: Yes, but I would need a `positionForUnknownParameterA` and `positionForUnknownParameterB` etc. to switch between, depending on how the user wants to sort them. Each sorting is delivered with their own call to the API, but I do not want to store the items multiple times in core data

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I am not quite sure I understand.

Comment: I have a heap of iteams, that are sorted by several fuzzy and secret algorithms on the server. No property in the model relates to these sortings. The apps get the order by API calls, where the items are returned in a specific order. The user is supposed to be able to pick from these sortings. More clear?

Comment: The solution is as I said. Introduce a numeric attribute called `serverOrder` and updated when necessary if it changes.